# Is there as.factor analogue in Julia?

Tags: julia, categorical-data

I have an integer column in dataframe. How can I convert its values into string in Julia?
In R a can simply write:

```
mutate(column2 = as.factor(column1))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Julia:

```
julia> using DataFramesMeta, CategoricalArrays

julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:3, b='a':'c')
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Char
─────┼─────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │     2  b
   3 │     3  c

julia> @transform!(df, :b = categorical(:b))
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Cat…
─────┼─────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │     2  b
   3 │     3  c
```

or `@transform` if you want a new data frame. Also target column name can be different e.g. `:b_categorical = categorical(:b)`.